# How can I make the function to wait before calling itself

Tags: java, android, function, recursion, time

Java, Android Studio

I have a function which deals cards, until everyone has got cards. I want to play a sound while dealing, and I want to stop the function, for 1 or 2 seconds, so it wont look like if I dealed all the cards in 0.1 sec. 
I have Already tried:

```
Thread.sleep();
```

I don't want to freeze my app, I just want the recursive function to wait before it calls itself.

Comment: Look into `Handler.postDelayed`

Comment: Don't use main thread or UI thread of your application & deal in Background thread you can sleep that thread so that application will not freeze.

Comment: isn't there any better solution other than adding delay to a thread? like using Asyn process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could play the sound and stop in in Handler with Handler().postDeleyed(). an abstract example would be like this:

```
//code to play sound
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run(){
          //stop the sound
     }
}, 1000); // 1000 is in millisec which means 1 seconds.
```

for example this piece of code will play and pause the music after 1 seconds:

```
final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = 
   this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.hangout_ringtone);
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), 
afd.getLength());
afd.close();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
player.prepare();
player.start();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }, 1000);//millisec.
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer i was looking for!